# Como usar el like en columnas agrupadas

Tags: sql-server

estoy tratando de encontrar las filas que comiencen con Au pero me esta reportando un error el sql server al utilizar el Description con el like dice: Ambiguous column name 'Description'.

```
Select A.NotesID, Coalesce( A.Description, B.Description ) as Description 
from MdPrNotes A Left Outer Join MDBIOPSYCHOSOCIALSETUPHDR B On
A.NoteCode = B.BioCode
Where Status = 'A' AND CanPatientEditIt = 'Y' AND Description like '%Au%' 
order by Description
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que no sabe por qué columna ordenarlo, ya que hay dos campos "description".

Prueba hacerlo así:

```
SELECT A.NotesID, Coalesce( A.Description, B.Description ) as Description 
FROM MdPrNotes A Left Outer Join MDBIOPSYCHOSOCIALSETUPHDR B On
A.NoteCode = B.BioCode
WHERE Status = 'A' AND CanPatientEditIt = 'Y'
  AND Coalesce(A.Description, B.Description) like '%Au%' 
ORDER BY Coalesce(A.Description, B.Description)
```

¡Suerte!

Comment: gracias por la ayuda Gustavo, ejecuto la consulta otra vez pero me reporta el mismo error, solo me funciona cuando le quito la condicion del like

Comment: No me di cuenta que en el where también lo tenías, ya modifiqué el código, por favor prueba ahora.

Comment: perfecto Gustavo muchas gracias por la ayuda, funciono